# MySQL error 1005

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1005

I am creating 3 tables in MySQL (Users, linkPosts, replyPosts)

The first two tables are executed fine, but I got an error when I am trying to insert the SQL of the replyPosts. The following is the SQL code of the three tables:

The first table SQL code: works fine

```
CREATE TABLE Users ( 
userName VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
password VARCHAR (20),
firstName VARCHAR (200),
lastName VARCHAR (200),
bio VARCHAR (160),
email VARCHAR (200),
country VARCHAR (200)
);
```

The code of the second table: works fine

```
CREATE TABLE linkPosts ( 
linkPostID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
link VARCHAR(255),
linkDescription VARCHAR (140), 
linkPostTime TIMESTAMP,
userName VARCHAR (20),
FOREIGN KEY (userName) REFERENCES Users(userName));
```

The third table where the error appears:

```
CREATE TABLE replyPosts ( 
replyPostID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
reply VARCHAR (140), 
replyPostTime TIMESTAMP,
userName VARCHAR (20),
linkPostID INT,
FOREIGN KEY (linkPostID) REFERENCES linkPosts(linkPostID),
FOREIGN KEY (userName) REFERENCES Users(userName));
```

The error I got as follows:

```
Error 1005 : Can't create table 'mdb_aa847.replyPosts' (errno: 150)
```

I have searched and tried other people's solutions but never worked. Any one can figure out where the error is?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This error is related to the foreign key constrains you add

Comment: please provide create table query of other 2 tables(Users, linkPosts) too

Comment: Apart from the error you are getting, why would you want to use a varchar column as foreign key? That will slow down the database. You will have to index that column, and then you will run into collation issues (uppercase, lowercase etc). Add a userId column to user's table, and use that for foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does table **replyPosts** already exist? This error can happen in case you have duplicate foreign key names. use [perror](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/perror.html) with the **errno** (in your case, its error 150), you should get:

```
MySQL error code 150: Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed
```

After looking at your complete SQL, I think it is down to the fact that **linkPostID is INT UNSIGNED** when you create **LinkPosts** table, whereas in **ReplyPosts** table, **linkPostID is INT**. Change that to **INT UNSIGNED** and see if it works.

As per the document here ["foreign keys"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) should have the same size and sign, if it's integer.

As a side note, I would still insist on using UserId as primary key on Users table instead of UserName. Every time you insert a record in Users table, it will be sorted by UserName (since it is primary key, hence clustered index). Bigger the UserName field (Varchar(20)), the longer it takes for sorting the whole table. As your table grows, inserting records into User table is going to get cumbersome.

Comment: no the replyPost table is not exist in my database, but I have the userName as a foreign key in another table.

Comment: Thanks so much, I have edited the linkPostID type from INT to INT UNSIGNED and i have it executed as u said.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the foreign key constraint

and since you are using `FOREIGN KEY (userName) REFERENCES Users(userName)`
which is a varchar, it is not possible in MYSQL to make a foreign reference on `varchar`

You can drop the foreign key constraint of the userName, and try with userId

Comment: I am considering the (userName) to be the primary key of the Users table. I have the userName as a foreign key for the second table and it works fine.  I have also tried to run the replyPosts table without the userName FK, but I got another error for the (linkPostID) foreign key

Comment: You can do one thing, create a field in userTable and make that primary key and from this table refer that field, and also make the userName a key in that table